# PHP x.509 Fingerprint -- deterministic?

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

Using PHP function "openssl_x509_fingerprint()" to produce a SHA1 hash of an X.509 certificate.

I run the code multiple times, and the results are different every time. The manual says it's deterministic, but unless there is supposed to be some random element I am unfamiliar with, it doesn't seem very deterministic to me.

Is this normal? Should I use some other mechanism to create a SHA1 hash?

Comment: No that's not normal. Yes it is deterministic. There's something wrong, post your code.

Comment: @Sammitch thank you very much for your suggestion! While putting together public-safe code to publish, I discovered that creating the x.509 certificate from the private key is what was changing at each run. OF COURSE creating a SHA1 on changing input results in changing output! I am supposing that the x.509 is different on each run because it includes a Time-to-Expire, so it must incorporate the current time somehow. So if I want the fingerprint to remain unchanged, I'll need to pre-generate the x.509 outside of the code. Thanks again!